# Reuse jQuery effect without having to constantly rewrite the effect for each class ID

Tags: jquery, html, coding-style

I have a question based on jQuery. I have classes/IDs in which I use the same jQuery effect. Therefore, I have to rewrite the effect each time I want to add it to another class/ID. Is there a way I do not have to rewrite the effect for each class/ID and just reuse the code?  I tried using multiple classes when targeting the effect **$('.classone','.classtwo')**  this resulted in the effect targeting all my classes at the same time. Below I have a example using checkboxes, if "other" is checked, content displays. Therefore, My goal is to reuse the jQuery code rather than rewriting the code for each class/ID. 
**Below is a example on how I wrote my code. Select One id has the same show and hide effect as Select Two. Feel free to provide feedbacks. If thumbs down, please let me know why, so I can improve. Thank you for your time.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*Select One- Displays input when "other" is selected*/
  $('#select_one').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'other') {
      $("#select_one_other").show();
    } else {
      $("#select_one_other").hide();
    }
  });




  /*Select Two - Displays input when "other" is selected*/
  $('#select_two').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'other') {
      $("#select_two_other").show();
    } else {
      $("#select_two_other").hide();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--Select One-->
<label style="margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold;width:100%;font-size:1.2em; color:#802753;opacity:.9;">
   <select id="select_one">
   <option selected value>Please select</option>
   <!--<option selected disabled>* State (for U.S only)</option>-->
   <option value="s">1</option>
   <option value="f">2</option>
   <option value="b">3</option>
   <option value="m">4</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
</label>


<div style='display:none;' id='select_one_other'>
<div class="form_content">
   <label class="label-effect" for="Other">If other, please specify</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" />
</div>
</div>

<!--Select Two-->
<label style="margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold;width:100%;font-size:1.2em; color:#802753;opacity:.9;">
   <select id="select_two">
   <option selected value>Please select</option>
   <!--<option selected disabled>* State (for U.S only)</option>-->
  <option value="s">1</option>
   <option value="f">2</option>
   <option value="b">3</option>
   <option value="m">4</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
</label>


<div style='display:none;' id='select_two_other'>
<div class="form_content">
   <label class="label-effect" for="Other">If other, please specify</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" />
</div>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/4eyzfnkj/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*Select One- Displays input when "other" is selected*/
  $('#select_one, #select_two').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'other') {
      $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_other').show();
    } else {
      $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_other').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold;width:100%;font-size:1.2em; color:#802753;opacity:.9;">
   <select id="select_one">
   <option selected value>Please select</option>
   <!--<option selected disabled>* State (for U.S only)</option>-->
   <option value="s">1</option>
   <option value="f">2</option>
   <option value="b">3</option>
   <option value="m">4</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
</label>


<div style='display:none;' id='select_one_other'>
<div class="form_content">
   <label class="label-effect" for="Other">If other, please specify</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" />
</div>
</div>

<!--Select Two-->
<label style="margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold;width:100%;font-size:1.2em; color:#802753;opacity:.9;">
   <select id="select_two">
   <option selected value>Please select</option>
   <!--<option selected disabled>* State (for U.S only)</option>-->
  <option value="s">1</option>
   <option value="f">2</option>
   <option value="b">3</option>
   <option value="m">4</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
</label>


<div style='display:none;' id='select_two_other'>
<div class="form_content">
   <label class="label-effect" for="Other">If other, please specify</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" />
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.